# Meaning of absolute values of flex-grow

Tags: css, flexbox

As I understand it, `flex-grow` on the child elements of a `flex`-ed element specifies how much of the relative proportion of space remaining to all the child elements should be allocated to a given element. So this:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
    <p style="flex-grow: 1; border: 1px solid purple;">First</p>
    <p style="flex-grow: 2; border: 1px solid gray;">Second</p>
</div>
```

means the second paragraph will take up twice as much of the remaining space as the first.

But if I change the absolute values of `flex-grow` while preserving the proportion between them:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
    <p style="flex-grow: .1; border: 1px solid purple;">First</p>
    <p style="flex-grow: .2; border: 1px solid gray;">Second</p>
</div>
```

the effect is not the same. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: my understanding is that flex-grow/shrink use only integers.

Comment: @fnostro If the non-integer values of flex-grow would be ignored, the width of the child elements in the second snippet would be the width of their contents. That isn't the case.

Comment: Decimals are permitted in Flexbox. `justify-background` though does not exist

Comment: `flex-basis` determines initial width of a flex item. `flex-grow/shrink` are integers that establishes proportions.  Flex bases has a few key words that determine what to do with content but they are not well defined as yet.  Though the `content` keyword (as well as fit-content, min-content, max-content) is not well defined across browsers, though i have not checked for a while.

Comment: decimal flex-grow is still affected by the contents of the elements. If you remove the text the sizing works correctly.

Comment: Read this for an explanation [how flex-grow calculates space: flex-grow is wierd](https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/)

Comment: @fnostro I don't see anything in the article which answers my question.

Comment: `flex-grow/shrink` work in conjunction with `flex-basis` which is why you should use `flex` with all three parameters, at least as a starting point.  By using just `flex-grow` the possibility exists for a `flex-grow: 1` to be larger than a `flex-grow:2` depending on respective content

Comment: Further reading: [CSS Tricks: A Complete Guide to flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @fnostro The two snippets have the same content in their respective child elements; the content of the child items is not relevant to the question. And AFAICT nothing in the second link you've commented answers the question.

Comment: The second link is just a nice explanation of all the flex options. The first article goes into the math of how flex manages the distribution of space.  It's not about the ratio you set but how flex chops up and distributes "grow" space.

Comment: @Paulie_D: If the math is accurate in [this link](https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/#aa-demonstration) then it seems integers are expected even though decimals are allowed. If you have a moment can you look it over and let me know your thoughts?  Granted the amount of space being distributed depends on content, gap size, default width, flex-grow/shrink/basis, and I think even box type.  but with regards to remaining space  the math goes off when the sum of the flex-grow values is below 1, at least if that article is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [flexbox draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#valdef-flex-flex-grow):

> Flex values between 0 and 1 have a somewhat special behavior: when the sum of the flex values on the line is less than 1, they will take up less than 100% of the free space.
>
> An item’s flex-grow value is effectively a request for some proportion of the free space, with 1 meaning “100% of the free space”; then if the items on the line are requesting more than 100% in total, the requests are rebalanced to keep the same ratio but use up exactly 100% of it. However, if the items request less than the full amount (such as three items that are each flex-grow: .25) then they’ll each get exactly what they request (25% of the free space to each, with the final 25% left unfilled). See § 9.7 Resolving Flexible Lengths for the exact details of how free space is distributed.
>
> This pattern is required for continuous behavior as flex-grow approaches zero (which means the item wants none of the free space). Without this, a flex-grow: 1 item would take all of the free space; but so would a flex-grow: 0.1 item, and a flex-grow: 0.01 item, etc., until finally the value is small enough to underflow to zero and the item suddenly takes up none of the free space. With this behavior, the item instead gradually takes less of the free space as flex-grow shrinks below 1, smoothly transitioning to taking none of the free space at zero.
>
> Unless this “partial fill” behavior is specifically what’s desired, authors should stick to values ≥ 1; for example, using 1 and 2 is usually better than using .33 and .67, as they’re more likely to behave as intended if items are added, removed, or line-wrapped.

In other words:

- if the total of all the `flex-grow`s is >= 1, **all** the remaining space will be distributed proportionate to the different `flex-grow` values. The actual values have no effect (e.g. 1:5 vs 2:10) as long as the proportions remain the same.
- if the total is < 1, only **part** of the remaining space will be distributed in the same proportion -- the part represented by the total. For example, if all the `flex-grow` values add up to .13, only 13% of the remaining space will be distributed. (This can be seen in the code snippet in [fnostro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264887/111794)).

The idea is that `flex-grow: 0` (on a single item) takes up none of the remaining space, and `flex-grow: 1` (or greater) takes up all of it; the values between 0 and 1 transition gradually between these two extremes. The same logic is applied when multiple items have a `flex-grow` set.

And so, in the second snippet of the question, the flexbox child items will only take up .3 or 30% of the free space, not all of it.

Answer (score 1):

All ratios are 1:2 in the snippet below.

Spacing, when the combined sum of flex-grow is below 1.0, displays as it's designed to do, but not as you'd expect. And content without specifying flex-basis affects spacing distribution as well

Distribution of remaining space, as far as I can tell, uses or at least expects, integers.  Meaning the flex-grow values represent proportions of the remaining space:

> 2. Next we have to determine how much one flex-grow is
>
> Now that we have the remaining space we need to determine into how
> many slices we want to cut it. **The important thing here is that we
> don’t divide the remaining space by the number of elements, but by the
> number of total flex-grow values**. So in our case that’s 3 (flex-grow:
> 2 + flex-grow: 1)
>
> 178 / 3 = 59.33
>
> remaining space / total flex-grow values = "one flex-grow"

So plugging your number into the equation,assuming the hypothetical space to be distributed is still 178 then you get:

> 178 / .3 = 593.33333

Which I'm assuming gets tossed out the window and you're left with defaults

```js
const ratio1to2 = [.01, .04, .08, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 50];

$(function() {
  ratio1to2.forEach(e => {
    let p2 = (e * 2);
    let html = `<div class="flexcontainer"><div style='flex-grow: ${e}'>${e}</div><div style='flex-grow: ${p2}'>${p2}</div></div>`;
    $("#placeholder1").append(html);
    $("#placeholder2").append(html);
  });
});
```

```css
div#placeholder1,
div#placeholder2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 4px;
}

.flexcontainer {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  gap: 4px;
}

.nobasis>.flexcontainer>div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.basis20pct>.flexcontainer>div {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder1" class="nobasis">
  No flex-basis, spacing not as expected
</div>
<div id="placeholder2" class="basis20pct">
  flex-basis 20% spacing more consistent.
</div>
```

Comment: All your examples demonstrate is that the actual amount by which `flex-grow` affects spacing is influenced by `flex-basis` when the `flex-grow` is < 1, which is reasonable; but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @ZevSpitz : I like your answer, as it shows the spec rather than my cited article.  My answer is showing how the extra space is carved up and how if the article is correct, fails below the value of 1. To me it seems the OP is trying to find out why the flex-grow for each `<p>` when set to `flex-grow` 1 and 2 respectively is not producing the same output as flex-grow : .1 and .2 respectively.   It's because the calculation is not taking the ratios of each flex-item against the whole, but a sum of the `grow` values against the whole.

Comment: What is the "whole" in this context? I'd assumed the whole would always be all the remaining space, which turns out not to be accurate -- if the total `grow` values is < 1, the whole will be only that part of the remaining space.

Comment: Apologies: you're correct in the example, "whole" refers to the space waiting to be "carved" up: the 178 value.  I based my answer on the article, not the spec.